# Как найти ошибку? Unity Android

Tags: android, unity3d

Драсьте. Во время проигрывания игры в Unity нет никаких ошибок, после сборки и установки на телефоне игра постоянно вылетает (в определенные моменты). Проверял пошагово (метод за методом), полностью переписал код, где (как мне кажется) был баг, вылеты продолжились. Вопрос вот в чем, есть ли какой-нибудь способ узнать, какая конкретно ошибка происходит? Рассмотрю все способы и теории, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Если получиться, то попробуйте подключить к компьютеру android устройство, с установленным **Unity Remote 5**, и через него запускать и проверять игру. Вам нужно запустить **Profiler**, и через него наблюдать проблемный момент.

Заранее надо отметить, что **Unity Remote 5** может не заработать. Тогда, если возможно, то попробуйте проверить всё на ios устройстве (даже если игра не для ios). Ибо он работает гораздо чаще, чем на android (вероятно потому, что разработчики "Unity Remote 5", поддерживают приложение для ios устройства в должной мере, чем android). Так или иначе, ошибка вероятно связана с игрой/компиляции игры, нежели с архитектурой самого устройства. Главное найти эту ошибку.

Если вы это пробовали, или это не помогает, есть другой спекулятивный вариант. Это просмотреть видео о том, как правильно настраивать Build на android, ведь там есть тонкости, которые не очевидны (в таком случае, с игрой всё в порядке, и проблема находится в компиляции самой игры на android).

В любом случае, сложно судить, из-за чего игра может не работать. Если она работает в Unity, но после компиляции происходят ошибки, то это может быть достаточно много вещей. И вполне индивидуальных, если это ошибка в коде/компиляции билда.

Comment: При использовании Unity Remote 5 никаких вылетов нет, игра проигрывается без багов, соответственно и в окне Profiler все "гладко". Сейчас скомпилирую игру под IOS, и буду думать, что делать дальше. Спасибо за помощь. П.С. Под андроид компилировал с настройками билда по умолчанию, наверняка билд осуществлялся некоректно)

Comment: Вероятно это так. Там есть много подводных камней при компиляции, которые желательно настроить, иначе ничего не работает при компиляции (или работает, но очень плохо). Но после настройки, всё работает просто отлично.
Точно не могу вспомнить, но есть несколько параметров, которые надо настраивать. Иначе работать игра будет некорректно, после билда на androind/ios.
ИМХО: Хорошо, что на стандартных настройках компиляции, у вас игра запускается. Лично у меня так не работает, и игра просто крашиться на экране загрузки, если не настроить в unity сам билд

Comment: у меня вылет происходит на этапе загрузки, если пробую запустить игру на планшете (android). Еще раз спасибо за помощь. Буду искать туториалы по грамотной настройке билда.